# libpango borked system Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dependencies

I was trying to install an application that complained I was using packages that were too new, and came across an article which said I could downgrade them by installing the following:

- libpango-1.0-0 (1.42.4-7)
- libpangocairo-1.0-0 (1.42.4-7)
- libpangoft2-1.0-0 (1.42.4-7)

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i libpango*.deb
```

[Link here][1]

Doing so seems to have broken my system, and I cannot launch most things.

They mentioned un-doing this by doing the following:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I get back the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-pango-1.0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
                Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
                Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
 libpango-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpango-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.42.4-7) but 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 is installed
 libpango-1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (< 1.44.7) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
                   Breaks: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (< 1.44.7) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
                   Breaks: libpango-1.0-0 (!= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
               Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
               Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.42.4-7) but 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 is 
 installed
 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (!= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is 
 installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.42.4-7) but 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 is 
 installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (!= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is 
 installed
 libpangoxft-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
                 Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
 nautilus : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.44.6) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
 pango1.0-tools : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
              Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
              Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is installed
  E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a 
  solution).
```

Would be amazing if someone could help me fix this, or just point me in the right direction so I can try to do so, rather than a re-install :)

**RESOLVED** Booted into Maintenance and selected Fix Broken Packages.

Comment: Thank you, I did remove it, but it doesn't seem linked to my issue. The issue is removing or updating libpango

Comment: Looking at those instructions, did you do the `sudo apt-mark hold package-name` line? If so, did you remember to *undo* it yet?

Comment: No, I never ran that command

Comment: But basically, I just want to completely remove libpango and install it again to it's correct version, but I keep getting those errors.

Comment: Show us the complete output of `sudo apt-mark showhold`

Comment: I ran the command, it was blank.

Comment: That's good. What application were you trying to install? A link would be helpful. Was it that Vectr from the linked question?

Comment: I didn't install it, but I downloaded it to my /Downloads directory. It was Mongo Management Studio. When trying to run the Electron binary, I got the following error: Pango-ERROR **: 03:53:41.569: Harfbuzz version too old (1.4.2). This is when I tried to do the downgrade  (stupidly) as per the link to the article I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install --reinstall libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0` ?

Comment: Yes, (and I really appreciate your help :) ) - I got the following:
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpangocairo-1.0-0_1.44.7-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpangocairo-1.0-0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64

Comment: when is the last time you ran `sudo apt update`? You should always start with this command before starting any session using `apt`, `apt-get` and `dpkg` commands.  If you use an outdated list of software to perform your package maintenance, you can get these dependency issues.

Comment: That error message indicates progress. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libpango-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0`. Let's do libpangocairo separately.

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I have done ``sudo apt update`` first, it says: ``2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.11. When I run that, it shows libpangocairo-1.0-0 and libpangoft2-1.0-0

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I have tried that, and every combination of the three. ``The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-pango-1.0 : Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.42.4-7) but 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 is to be installed Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).``

Comment: RESOLVED: Booted into Maintenance and selected Fix Broken Packages.

Comment: Please don't put the problem resolution in your question. Post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: Booted into Maintenance and selected Fix Broken Packages.